# How I print the ALOGI(...) in Android C++ file?

Tags: android, c++

For example, there is a ALOGI("there is a log") function in dalvik/vm/native/dalvik_system_DexFile.cpp, and I want to see this log in logcat or DDMS.

How can I do this? Please be specific. Thanks.

Comment: Are you building your own Android ROM? If not, I'm not sure you can alter what Dalvik will be logging. If you _are_ building your own ROM, then try modifying the CFLAGS for the relevant module in the relevant Android.mk file. For example, adding `-UNDEBUG -DDEBUG=1 -DLOG_NDEBUG=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to print logs is to create a header crossplatform to this task. In example, with the following logger.h:

```
#pragma once

#define TMB_DEBUG_LOGS 1

#ifdef TMB_DEBUG_LOGS
// YES LOGS
#   ifdef ANDROID
    // LOGS ANDROID
#       include <android/log.h>
#       define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#       define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#       define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO   , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#       define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN   , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#       define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#   else
    // LOGS NO ANDROID (fprintf)
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <time.h>

        //Warning, multithreading problem in logs with this solution!
        static char buff[100];
        static struct tm *sTm;
        static time_t now;
#       define PRINT_TIME {now = time(0); sTm = localtime(&now); strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%M]", sTm); fprintf(stderr, "%s ", buff); }
#       define LOGV(...) {PRINT_TIME fprintf(stderr, "[V][%s] ", LOG_TAG); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); fprintf(stderr, "\n");}
#       define LOGD(...) {PRINT_TIME fprintf(stderr, "[D][%s] ", LOG_TAG); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); fprintf(stderr, "\n");}
#       define LOGI(...) {PRINT_TIME fprintf(stderr, "[I][%s] ", LOG_TAG); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); fprintf(stderr, "\n");}
#       define LOGW(...) {PRINT_TIME fprintf(stderr, "[W][%s] ", LOG_TAG); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); fprintf(stderr, "\n");}
#       define LOGE(...) {PRINT_TIME fprintf(stderr, "[E][%s] ", LOG_TAG); fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); fprintf(stderr, "\n");}
#   endif // ANDROID
#else
// NO LOGS
#   define LOGV(...)
#   define LOGD(...)
#   define LOGI(...)
#   define LOGW(...)
#   define LOGE(...)
#endif // TMB_DEBUG_LOGS
```

In your source, in example, main.c

```
//... your includes
#define LOG_TAG "MainProgram"
#include "logger.h"

main()
{
   // My code
   LOGI("The program is creating a info log");
   LOGD("My foo: %d", foo_variable);
}
```